# How would you filter out a dynamic array using a dynamic array (Non exact match)?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

This is a follow up to the question I posted yesterday. I have two dynamic arrays in excel, as shown in the image. One is C1#, which is the criteria for the search, and one is F1#, which is the dynamic array I want to search in. I want to get the dynamic array output as shown in the Wanted Output. I am able to get this output, however I am not sure how to get it to output "None", which includes the word "One", I am currently only able to get it to output exact matches. Is there any way to do this without requiring exact matches? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `I1`

```
=LET(
     a,TOROW("*"&C1#&"*"),
     b,SEQUENCE(ROWS(C1#),,,0),
     IF(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(a,F1#))),b),F1#,""))
```

---

Comment: Thank you! This does work, however if I have User Input that isnt in the F1 Dynamic Array, such as "Three", I am getting a #VALUE error. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @SStaple you mean to say you have only `Three` and no `One` & `Twos`? I don't get any error.

Comment: Nevermind, It actually does not give an error, it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SStaple glad to know it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

ALternatively:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=REPT(F1:F9,BYROW(ISERR(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(A2,","),F1:F9)),LAMBDA(r,1-AND(r))))
```

Comment: Cool Sir. Nice use `REPT()`